# how to write the console output to a file in c

Tags: c

hi i have the following code

```
int main()
{
   system("netsh interface ip show addresses");

}
```

and the output in the console to be written to a text file or else to a variable. pleaase help me out with this.   THANKS in ADVANCE

Comment: Use `popen()` rather than `system()`.

Comment: can you please explain that how to write it in a file

Comment: As commented already, use `popen` to run the command instead of `system`. Then use any of the input functions such as `fread` and `fgets` to read from the file stream returned by `popen`. Then use output functions such as `write` and `fwrite` to write the data back to file.

Comment: my friend, obviously. what else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use Linux, try this:

```
system("netsh interface ip show addresses > /path/to/file 2>&1 ");
```

Comment: good one. But also include the `exec` family version. `system` is costly.

Answer (score 1):

```
void do_popen()
    FILE *pf;
    char command[200];

    // Execute a process listing
    sprintf(command, "netsh interface ip show addresses"); 

    // Setup our pipe for reading and execute our command.
    if(!(pf= popen(command, "r"))){
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pclose(pf) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr," Error: Failed to close command stream \n");

    return;
}
```

Here we are using *popen* which internally creates a process and run the command given to it. It returns an I/O stream from where the data can be fetched later. `read` and `write` system calls are being used while reading from the given command buffer or writing into the file back

To make it more generic, you can pass the command in the function parameter and return the data stored into the file in a dynamic array.

Although it is done nicely using `popen` but it creates a separate process where it run these commands as `sh` commands,and then put it in the file and before returning the file pointer, it closes all the process.

I would rather implement my own child process using `fork()` and then use `exec` and implement my own `SIGCHILD` handler to remove it from zombie and keep on processing other work in parallel instead of blocking the process

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below code will help to solve your issue. Look at the [man pages for the details of popen and pclose APIs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];
    if(!(in = popen("netsh interface ip show addresses", "r"))){
        return -1;
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        printf("%s", buff);
    }
    pclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about explaining it? The OP will learn **nothing** from just code without understanding it.

Comment: And then the code is even bad. A function declaration within a function definition? Really? Why `exit(1);` if `return 1;` does it and why not the portable `return EXIT_FAILURE;`?

Comment: He needs to look at the man pages of the APIs to understand the code. At least some effort should be put from his side, shouldn't he?

Comment: Yes, of course, but what does your answer contribute to that? How does he learn how to read man pages? If I hadn't written these comments you wouldn't have mentioned man pages at all. Read [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) on code-only answers.

Comment: @cad You are right. I had to mention about man pages. I'll update my answer.